Convert a list/data frame (R) to a data.table in databricks
I have created an object in Databricks R by running the following command :-
data1_df <- spark_read_table(sc, "data1") 

The object type apparently is "list"
Partial structure of the object is like so :-
List of 6
 $ ChildObjectName      :List of 1
  ..$ con:List of 10
  .. ..$ master     : chr "sparklyr://localhost:65529/65529"
  .. ..$ method     : chr "gateway"
  .. ..$ app_name   : chr "sparklyr"
  .. ..$ config     :List of 8
  .. .. ..$ sparklyr.cancellable                     : logi FALSE
  .. .. ..$ spark.env.SPARK_LOCAL_IP.local           : chr "127.0.0.1"
  .. .. ..$ sparklyr.connect.csv.embedded            : chr "^1.*"
  .. .. ..$ spark.sql.legacy.utcTimestampFunc.enabled: logi TRUE
  .. .. ..$ sparklyr.connect.cores.local             : int 96
  .. .. ..$ spark.sql.shuffle.partitions.local       : int 96
  .. .. ..$ sparklyr.shell.name                      : chr "sparklyr"
  .. .. ..$ spark.r.libpaths                         : chr "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/rEnv-2742b6da-b682-4cbd-bd6a-5b7b3c426ff4,/databricks/spark/R/lib,/local_disk0"| __truncated__
  .. ..$ state      :<environment: 0x55f774bed4e0> 
  .. ..$ spark_home : NULL
  .. ..$ backend    : 'sockconn' int 7
  .. .. ..- attr(*, "conn_id")=<externalptr> 
  .. ..$ monitoring : 'sockconn' int 8

It contains 1500940 rows.
I am trying to create a data.table object (R) by reference using this command :-
setDT(data1_df) 

and get this error all the time :-
Error in setDT(data1_df) : 
  All elements in argument 'x' to 'setDT' must be of same length, but the profile of input lengths (length:frequency) is: [5:1, 3:2, 1:3]
The first entry with fewer than 5 entries is 1
Error in setDT(data1_df): All elements in argument 'x' to 'setDT' must be of same length, but the profile of input lengths (length:frequency) is: [5:1, 3:2, 1:3]
Error in setDT(data1_df): All elements in argument 'x' to 'setDT' must be of same length, but the profile of input lengths (length:frequency) is: [5:1, 3:2, 1:3]
The first entry with fewer than 5 entries is 1

I don't understand why. Any suggestions on this would be a great help. Where am I going wrong?
But when I run this command, it works, although takes 9 minutes.
Best regards
Deepak

setDT takes the list and tries to generate an indexed data.table data frame, which needs the same list element length. Minimal example e.g. setDT(list(1:5, 1:6)). On the other hand data.table(list(1:5, 1:6)) works because it simply puts the list elements per line into an indexed data.table structure.

Thank you. Didn't see it earlier. Sorry.. How do you accept the answer?

Gonna write an answer from the comment that can be accepted.

setDT takes the list and tries to generate an indexed data.table data frame, which needs the same list element length.
A minimal example could be
library(data.table)

lst <- list(1:5, 1:6)

setDT(lst)

Error: All elements in argument 'x' to 'setDT' must be of same length, but 
the profile of input lengths (length:frequency) is: [5:1, 6:1]
The first entry with fewer than 6 entries is 1.

On the other hand
data.table(lst)
           lst
        <list>
1:   1,2,3,4,5
2: 1,2,3,4,5,6

works because it simply puts the list elements per line into an indexed data.table structure.
